# VSCode fold docstrings Python MacOS

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I have tried using the command:

`>Fold Level 2` and it is causing too much folding.

And

`>Fold Level 3` does not fold the methods' docstrings.

My primary goal is to fold the docstrings and nothing else.

```
def test(a, b, c):
    """A lot of multiline
    docstrings here
    that dont get folded
    """
    return ...
```

would turn into:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    return ...
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

[By default VS Code's cold folding is indentation-based, unaware of the programming language used](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3422). Aside from Brett's answer, one hack is to indent the docstring.

```
def test(a, b, c):
    """[short summary]

        [indented long summary parameters returns etc.]
    ^^^^
    """

    return ...
```

This is clearly a bad idea for anything professional, but it works.

---

[Towards the end of Brett's link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1847#issuecomment-808990258) one can find a new comment that would allow the Python extension to fold docstrings properly. The comment contains instructions for MacOS. On my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS machine, I did the following instead:

1. Run `which code`. I got `/usr/bin/code`, but that was linked to `/usr/share/code/bin/code`.
2. Copy the directory `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/python` to `~/.vscode/extensions`.
3. Add the regex below to `~/.vscode/extensions/python/language-configuration.json`.

```
{
  "folding": {
    "offSide": true,
    "markers": {
      "start": "^\\s*#\\s*region\\b|^\\ *\"{3}(?!.*\"{3}).+",
      "end": "^\\s*#\\s*endregion\\b|^\\ *\"{3}$"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not at the moment. Please upvote the [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1847) if you would like to see this supported.